# Asterisk-Java define Asterisk version programmatically

Tags: java, asterisk, asterisk-java

I'm using Asterisk Java v 2.0.4.

I'm using ManagerConnection to connect to a Grandstream [UCM6202](http://www.grandstream.com/products/ip-pbxs/ucm-series-ip-pbxs/product/ucm6200-series) that is based on a Asterisk 13 version.

When I run my application I get this log:

```
          main] o.a.m.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl     : Successfully logged in
2019-05-03 15:27:44.986 ERROR 17108 --- [           main] o.a.m.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl     : Unable to determine asterisk version, assuming 1.6... you should expect problems to follow.
2019-05-03 15:27:44.987  INFO 17108 --- [           main] o.a.m.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl     : Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.6
```

is there a way to define programmatically Asterisk version?

Answer (score 1):

No, Asterisk Java does not have a way for you to tell it which version of Asterisk it is connecting to. Asterisk Java determines the version of Asterisk by interacting directly with Asterisk.

Asterisk Java is open source though so you always have the option to suggest changes to the maintainers/developers or fork the project and customize it for your own use. It looks like the version detection code is all centralized in one place: https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/asteriskjava/AsteriskVersion.java#L200